# Google pie chart using php, mysql and jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, google-pie-chart

I am creating google piecharts but here I have to used iframe to show this chart,
but I want to show it by ajax and without iframe....
Is there any way to show google piechart without iframe??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link given by @Grrbrr404 is not working anymore so, you can try it like,

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "getData.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
}

</script>
```

Before adding above script add a div having id `chart_div` in you html like,

```
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Show this **[php-example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the google chart api to show the piechart with pure javascript.

[See this page for example code](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart.html#Example).